# Leadership types for DevOps team?

Tags: culture

Would you say from experience, either task or relationship leadership style works better for DevOps?
Or would you go for something else in this context than [Forsyth's theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Task-oriented_and_relationship-oriented_leadership)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Different types of leadership styles are required. To start with DevOps in a company, one has to apply a different leadership style compared to when it has already been implemented.

When one starts with DevOps a cultural change has to be done and engineers should get rid of, for example, the "throw it over the wall" mindset. When DevOps has been implemented, a leader should be able to communicate well with other teams to connect multiple departments in a company.

In summary, in the beginning a leadership style that motivates people to implement DevOps is required. Later communication between teams and how the team will work in the organization, i.e. more focus on external.

A leadership style that could be used to implement DevOps is a transformational leadership style.

Answer (score 0):

Healthy DevOps teams tend to be relatively small and relatively independent when they work really well. If you have a team like this, then task oriented leadership will work well because it fits nicely with the general DevOps philosophy.